# Why are there two blinds in Texas Hold 'em instead of just one?

Tags: texas-hold-em, blinds

If the primary [purpose of blinds is to build pot equity for the pre-flop betting round](https://poker.stackexchange.com/q/1006/4307), why are there *two* blinds (**Small Blind** and **Big Blind**) instead of just a one?

Would not a single blind accomplish the task of building pot equity for the players, as well as provide motivation for the blind player to participate with an otherwise unwanted hand?

Since the blind still rotates around the table to each player, each player will still be motivated to play their hand in order to recoup chips lost from the blind responsibility. If the size of the pot is a concern, the single blind could provide the equivalent value of the combined **Small Blind** and **Big Blind**.

Similarly, why have the two blinds differ (**Small Blind** = half **Big Blind**) rather than both be the same amount?

Comment: Enough is relative.  More equity is more equity.    Unwanted hand is relative.  So you think a hand would play the same if you had 1 bb versus 1.5 bb to start.  A 50% difference still would make no real difference in equity?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of blinds?](http://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/1006/what-is-the-purpose-of-blinds)

Comment: @Paparazzi There must be some rationale for splitting it between two players rather than requiring a single player match 1.5 Big Blind. This rationale is what I'm trying to understand.

Comment: It is the dynamic of a forced bet and a forced raise.  That is different than one force bet of the same total.   If combined a call would be a different amount.  What is the purpose of a min raise?    They picked some rules that seems to work.   You could change if you want for a home game.

Comment: Without two blinds how would you ever have a battle of the blinds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blinds are the essence of poker games. All strategy is built on the basis of stealing the money that are already in the pot (Dead money). Without the blinds, a player can fold every hand but Aces, thus (in the long term) would never lose money.

Now, there are different setups to achieve that, like big and small blinds, two big blinds, blinds with antes, antes only, blinds with antes and straddles, Mississippi straddles etc.

Why the traditional "Big-Small blind" setup is more common, one argument is that it creates action between (at least) two people in each hand, while what you suggested with just one Super Big blind, would just force the player to call initial raisers more frequently, changing slightly the character of the game as we know it. Still, viable though.

Answer (score 5):

There are multiple problems with the proposal that 1 player put up 1.5xBB rather than as it is actually played.

1. a $1-$2 game would then just become a more expensive game as now it would cost $3 to limp, and $6 to (min) raise rather than $2 and $4.
2. Having 2 blinds gives 2 players equity in the pot rather than just one presumably creating more action.  A player with some equity in the pot (Even just 1/2 BB) is more likely to defend with a marginal hand than someone with no equity in the pot.

Answer (score 0):

all poker games use somedevice such as antes blind or forced openning bet to get something to play for in the  pot.Blinds have evvolved into the preferred method for BUtton games like holdem, Omaha Holdem and DRaw games. STud games ten toward ANte and a forced bringin.A new trend in tournament poker is to have the big blind also post antes for thewhole table. this seems to be a good thing as far as speeding up the collection of antes.

plscing big blinds and Antes on a game has to general eeffectes increasing the action and evening the field  up.
using big blinds and antes makes a tight style of play less profitable, simply because it costs a lot more in antes and blinds waiting for hands, so for most games with antes and big blinds optomial play tendstoward  looser play.

if your a game operator big blinds and antes will make your game faster and muchmore interestig for your player and there will not be as many big wins leaving the table making games last longerand the money on the table tends to go around and down the slot. measning in casino terms a muchbetter hold after costs and better net wins.